# Pasar datos a un componente del Router

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Estoy intentando realizar una sencilla aplicación, la cual se compone de 3 componentes: **SearchComponent**, **ListComponent** y **DetailComponent**, el esquema sería tal que asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siendo el **SearchComponent** visible en todas las vistas, y los otros 2 componentes enrutados metidos en un router-outlet.

Mi problema es, cómo hago para que en el primer caso (de la imagen), que lo que busque en el **SearchComponent** me filtre la lista que contiene el **ListComponent**, y si estoy en DetailComponent, que al buscar algo en el **SearchComponent**, me redirija al primer caso filtrando ya la lista.

Lo que tengo ahora, es que al darle a buscar, me lleve a la ruta: *mipagina.com/s/palabra_que_he_puesto* y este path use el ListComponent.
Os dejo parte de la aplicación de como lo tengo:

**search.html**

```
<header>
<div class="tab">
    <div class="tab_center">
        <div class="search_wrapper">
            <input #search (change)="handleChange(search.value)" placeholder="Buscar...">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**search.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {Course} from './course';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
   selector: 'course-search',
   templateUrl: 'app/courses/course-search.html'
})

export class CourseSearchComponent { 

    constructor(private router: Router){}

    handleChange(search:string){
        this.router.navigate(['/s', search]);
    }
}
```

**list.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Course} from './course';
import {CourseService} from './course.service';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';


@Component({
   templateUrl: 'app/courses/course-list.html',
   providers: [CourseService]
})

export class CourseListComponent implements OnInit{
   public courses:Course[];
   public ErrorMessage: string;
   private sub: Subscription;

   constructor(private courseData:CourseService, private router: Router,     private route: ActivatedRoute){
      this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        let search_key = params['search_key'];
        if(search_key){
            this.courses = this.courses.filter(element =>    element.name.indexOf(search_key)!==-1);
        }
        });
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.getCourses();
    }


    getCourses(){
        this.courseData.getCourses().subscribe(
        result => {
            if(!result){
                alert("Error en el servidor");
            }else{
                this.courses = result;
            }
        },
        error => {
            this.ErrorMessage = <any>error;
            if(this.ErrorMessage){
              alert("Error en la petición");
            }
        })
    }
    onSelect(course: Course) {
        this.router.navigate(['/course', course.id]);
    }
}
```

**detail.component**

```
import {Component, Output, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {CourseService} from './course.service';

@Component({
    template: `Seleccionado el curso con id {{course}}`
})


export class CourseDetailComponent implements OnInit{ 

    private sub: Subscription;
    private course: number;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private service: CourseService) {}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.course = params['id'];
        });
    }
}
```

Estoy usando Angular 2 RC5

**SOLUCIONADO**: No había importado bien las rutas en el modulo :S

Comment: podrías poner el codigo de detailcomponent?

Comment: Añadido el componente "detail"

Comment: entonces, no hay mucho que hacer ! jajaja pon tu mismo una respuesta, indicando que error cometiste y como lo encontraste. Quien sabe si a otra persona le pasa algo así y puede iluminarse gracias a ti. Saludos!

Comment: @AlejandroAntolin podrías poner el detalle de lo que has hecho como respuesta y poner dicha respuesta como aceptada, así se vé que has solucionado el problema.